# Not perfoming an action when there's no data

Tags: ios, swift

I have an action opening an URL when tapping a button, I was wondering how can I program it so that when `Facebook = "0"`, an `UIAlertController` appears.

The code updated and functioning properly is:

```
let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Facebook", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) in

   if self.facebook == "0" {

     let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Lo sentimos", message: "La cofradía no dispone de Facebook, inténtalo a través de otro medio", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Atrás", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

       alert.addAction(action1)
       self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil);

        } else {

          UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://facebook.com/\(self.facebook)")!)

 }
```

Comment: Now you're opening the alert when `facebook` isn't `"0"`, when it seem like you want to open the alert when `facebook == "0"`

Comment: I figured it out. I update my code for someone with the same problem

Comment: Also make it clear that your code is now functioning properly in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if it's empty before opening the URL:

```
// I'm assuming facebook is a String that is empty if it isn't set

if facebook != "" {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://facebook.com/\(self.facebook)")!)
} else {
    // Open alertcontroller here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice what my partner did in the JSON. I update my question